# PHP - Load HTML from a fully loaded external page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, parsing

I'm new to AJAX and php and have been trying to figure out how use a PHP HTML DOM Parser to fetch the html from an external site. However, the html fetched is the one immediately loaded into DOM and I require elements which are included later on in the page via Javascript. How do I fetch the latter with PHP.

Example: When I use my parser to load: http://csgo.exchange/id/76561198078821986
the big numerical value in the h3 tag on the left is "0.00" because the h3 tag is loaded into dom with a value of "0.00" and later modified to its real value via Javascript. How do I fetch the real value?

Comment: Note: The h3 is not 0.00 on my end. It's 170157.72 and it is not changed by js. It comes with the html.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't use the PHP Parser on that page is because it doesn't run the javascript, only the HTML.

If you insist on getting the data from that page you'll need a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Otherwise the way to get the data is to find where the javascript is getting it from and pass the same variables.

In your case it's: http://csgo.exchange/inventory/76561198078821986/retry/

You can now parse this URL with the PHP HTML Parser instead and get the values you need.

A good rule to keep is to always try to find the data in it's rawest form either as `html` or `json`. Chrome's network tab is your best friend.

Comment: Incredible! I might cry with joy. Am I understanding correctly? You found out tha the page is loading it's data from "http://csgo.exchange/inventory/76561198078821986/retry/" by analysing the Network tab in the Chrome console?
Is this a universally applicable method?

Comment: Yes. The network tab will show you everything else that was loaded after the initial page load inluding js, css and images. You can select XHR to filter ajax content only.